# Как принять картинку от пользователя pytelegrambotapi

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Надо чтобы когда пользователь отправлял  /start бот отправлял сообщения 'Отправь фото' и если пользователь отправлял фото то сохранял его а если не фото то отправлял  сообщения 'не тот формат файла отправьте фото' и так по кругу. Буду благодарен за ответ

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

Для этого нужно использовать хендлер. Для него указать, что нужно ждать от пользователя фотографии.

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['photo'])
def photo_id(message):
    photo = max(message.photo, key=lambda x: x.height)
    print(photo.file_id)
```

Этот код принимает только фотографии. Далее запускает функцию *photo_id*, после чего из сообщения вытягивает фотографию и получает его ID. Дальше по этому ID уже можно будет легко отослать фото

Если нужна проверка на фото, то можно просто смотреть, что лежит в message

Для начала напиши `print(message)` и там смотри, какой тип сообщения отправлен

Answer (score 0):

Этот код выгружает картинку, которую прислал пользователь:

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['photo'])
def photo(message):   
     fileID = message.photo[-1].file_id   
     file_info = bot.get_file(fileID)
     downloaded_file = bot.download_file(file_info.file_path)
     with open("image.jpg", 'wb') as new_file:
         new_file.write(downloaded_file)
```

Этот код отвечает на любой текст:

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types = ['text'])
def bot_message(message):
    if message.chat.type == 'private':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Отправьте картинку.")
```

Это ответ на команду `/start`:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Отправьте картинку.")
```